# form submission - events triggered on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I am looking for what events get triggered on a page when a url is changed.

My specific example is.

say you have a button on your page that points to "myfile.exe"

now when clicked the browser does not change the page, it simply shows a download prompt for the file.

What events does this trigger?

does it cause window.location to change?
are there any specific events you can hook into to detect this type of activity on your page?

Comment: A button by itself doesn't point to anything. A form might and so would a link... they both react differently depending on the actual scenario. What it is you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you click on a link or a button inside a webpage the event and behavior is always the same. The difference when you see a download prompt is because the browser itself doesn't know how to render to resource so the best action it can do is give you the chance to save the file.
An exe file is not a type of file a browser knows how to deal with.
For more info google for the http header "content-type"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you are wanting...

Once thing you could do is make it so that your button go to a javascript function instead of just to the file. Then, after you have done whatever you want to do in your javascript function, you can send the file to the user.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/robertphyatt/8cJmE/3/